# meaning of "was tempted"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tempt?q=tempt):
**(1)** *He was tempted into a life of crime*.
**(2)** *I was tempted to take the day off*.

Does (1) mean (1a) or (1b)?:
**(1a)** *A life of crime attracted him but we don't know whether he got involved in crime or not*.
**(1b)** *He got involved in crime*.

Does (2) mean (2a) or (2b)?:
**(2a)** *Taking the day off attracted him but we don't know whether he did it or not*.
**(2b)** *He took the day off*.

Comment: Your first example implies he *did* succumb to the temptation (and lived a life of crime), but the second one is different - I'd normally assume *he resisted the temptation* (he stayed at work). But this is just inference in both cases. Being "tempted" literally says *nothing whatsoever* about one's actual reaction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please write answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @MJ713: I closevoted. The literal meaning of "tempt" is easily established from dictionaries. The actual likely *result* depends on context. Of course, there are implications to using various prepositions  - *tempted **into*** implies succumbing more strongly than *tempted **by***, for example. But that's more than I wanted to get involved in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree that this is answerable by a dictionary because dictionaries don't tend to include changes in meaning due to prepositions. Though it's more than you wanted to get involved in, I believe that's the essential question here, not the definition of "tempt", which the OP has obviously already looked up.

Comment: @gotube: You're quite right, and I've retracted my closevote accordingly. It was lazy of me to only think of context + the literal dictionary definition of "tempt". I wouldn't have made that mistake if the OP had asked about the difference between 1) *I was tempted **to take** the day off* and 2) *I was tempted **into taking** the day off.* (Answer: 1 ... but I didn't, 2 ... so I did). (But the OP could hardly be expected to know that! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be *tempted **into** doing something* means to actually do it because of the temptation.

To merely be *tempted **to** do something* (without "into") only means wanting to do something. It doesn't mean they did it.

So the answers are 1b and 2a